# How to store data in two columns request from one input in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

#### Input field

```
<label>Longitude, Latitude <i class="light"> (Optional)</i></label>
<input type="text" value="{{old('lat_long')}}" name="lat_long" placeholder="Latitude, Longitude" class="form-control form-control-md"
```

#### table

```
$table->string('lat')->nullable();
$table->string('long')->nullable();
```

Comment: You could use [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to separate the input value, but you'd need to validate the data to ensure it was submitted in a valid format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assume user will put `lat_long` like `lat,lang` so here you have separator with `,`

in this case you can use [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```php
$latLong = request('lat_long')

try{
    $latLongArray = explode(",",$latLong);

    $lat = $latLongArray[0];
    $long = $latLongArray[1];
}catch (\Exception $e){
    throw new \Exception("Latitude and Longitude are not valid");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify [pattern or regex](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp). Then use [regex](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-regex) in laravel validation. Then create a function to [explode](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp) the input and you'll get 2 inputs.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
$table->string('lat_long')->nullable();
```

so,you can save data of ***39,107*** ,when you need use,you can ***explode(',', "39,107")***